# Add marker to projected coordinates from form-input Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, javascript, proj4js

I am working on a Leaflet map and trying to use an input form to insert my local coordinates that will be projected to WGS84 and displayed on map as a marker but when I try it the button seems not to work. I don't know if it's a Javascript syntax related issue or I am misusing Proj4.

[image]

Here is the code:

HTML

```
         X: <input type="number" id='latt'>
         Y: <input type="number" id='lngg'>
         <button onclick="addmarker()">addmarker</button>
```

Javascript

```
            // convert coordinates to Moroccan system
        var secondProjection = "+proj=lcc +lat_1=29.7 +lat_0=29.7 +lon_0=-5.4 +k_0=0.9996155960000001 +x_0=500000 +y_0=300000 +a=6378249.2 +b=6356515 +towgs84=31,146,47,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs";
        var firstProjection ="+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs "
        //add markers based on insertion
        function addmarker() {
            var inputlat = document.getElementById('latt').value;
            var inputlng = document.getElementById('lngg').value;
            var pj = proj4(secondProjection,firstProjection,[inputlat,inputlng]);
            var x = pj[0];
            var y = pj[1];
            var latlng = L.latLng(x,y);
            L.marker(latlng).addTo(map);  
        };
```

EDIT: Type = "number" instead of "float"

Comment: Your code adds a marker instead of zooming, is that intended? Your question is about zooming. Have you zoomed out to the full world view to see if it was added in the wrong place maybe?

Comment: I am sorry that was a mistake I edited the title, its actually about the projection because I tried both zooming and adding a marker and it doesnt work.

Comment: Your inputs should be `type="number"`, there is no `type="float"` option in HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem comes from the fact that proj4 uses `[lng, lat]` coordinate order, but Leaflet uses `[lat, lng]` order for input to it's functions and methods.

To distinguish between projected and unprojected coordinates, it's also good to use naming `[x, y]` for projected and `[lat, lng]` for unprojected coordinates.

Your code could then look something like this:

```
 X: <input type="float" id="x">
 Y: <input type="float" id="y">
 <button onclick="addmarker()">addmarker</button>
```

```
var secondProjection = "+proj=lcc +lat_1=29.7 +lat_0=29.7 +lon_0=-5.4 +k_0=0.9996155960000001 +x_0=500000 +y_0=300000 +a=6378249.2 +b=6356515 +towgs84=31,146,47,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs";
var firstProjection ="+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs "

function addmarker() {
    var inputX = document.getElementById('x').value;
    var inputY = document.getElementById('y').value;
    var pj = proj4(secondProjection, firstProjection, [inputX, inputY]);
    var lng = pj[0];
    var lat = pj[1];
    var latlng = L.latLng(lat, lng);
    L.marker(latlng).addTo(map);  
};
```

Here is working example at JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/TomazicM/2tw9gfbe/

If you input coordinates `[262815, 524520]`, you'll get location near Marrakech:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Ive tried to edit my code but the button doesnt display any marker on the map.

Comment: Do you get any errors in browser debugger console? What do you get if you do `console.log(lng, lat)`? Can you add an example of valid projected coordinates `[x, y]` and where this should be on the map ( `[lng, lat]`).

Comment: I added JSFiddle example.

Comment: Thank you for the efforts, it helped me, but what actually solved the problem is that I added `parseFloat` to `document.getElementById('x').value` and  `document.getElementById('y').value` and it worked! Please add this to your answer so I can mark it as accepted!

Comment: I'm no JS expert, but for me it works also without `parseFloat`, as you can see in my JSFiddle example. Maybe you have some different version of proj4.js which accepts only numbers. And by the way, as far as I know there is no such `input` element type as `float`, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input

Comment: I changed type to`text` and  set `var inputX=parseFloat(document.getElementById('x').value)` and `var inputY=parseFloat(document.getElementById('y').value)` and it worked.

Comment: There is now a mismatch between the attempted answer and what was found in its comments. Yet the answer was accepted. @TomazicM it would be awesome if you could change it to be just about the parsing as it turned out to be the actual issue. Thanks! :)

Comment: @bugmenot123 Have a good look at the code in the question. The main problem was coordinate order. Parsing was additional problem that I was not able to reproduce.

Comment: We could argue that if they had had the marker displayed they would have found the swapping problem as smaller problem. ;D